# Reference to connectionstring in settings

Tags: c#, winforms

This is for a Windows Application.

In a class I want to referee to my connectionstring called freighthelper which is located in the settings.settings file in my project. How do I do this?

I have tried with this without success.

```
_connection.ConnectionString = FreightHelper.Properties.Settings.Default.freighthelper;
```

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. What problem are you seeing? Any error message?

Comment: Does it work if your remove that first *FreightHelper*?

Comment: if that code compiles, then the setting must exist.
You should explain more details about "without success":
Was the ConnectionString wrong or empty after trying to get it (probably easy to solve)? Or did you just not succeed in connecting to the database (much more possibilities for errors)?

Comment: Sorry, the code was correct but the problem was that I used code for SQL-database instead of OleDb. You got me to realize this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to store your connection string in a settings file? It is usually put in the config file and retrieved like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: It seams like my connectionstring already is stored in the config file like this.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `_connection.ConnectionString=Settings.Default. freighthelper;`  to read form  a setting files.

NOte: connection string better to place in `App.confing`

E.g:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name" connectionString="Data Source=Instance Name;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```